# Gnuplot output encoding

Tags: gnuplot, input-encodings, epslatex

I have this gnuplot script and works fine:

```
set term png
set output 'test.png'

plot sin(x) ti "Eñe"
```

Note de 'ñ' in the label. This produces an image and you can read the 'ñ'.
Now I try to change the term to `epslatex`:

```
set term epslatex color
set output 'test.tex'

plot sin(x) ti "Eñe"
```

Run gnuplot, and it generates `test.tex` and `test.eps`. Then I have a master file:

```
% master.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\input{test.tex}
\end{document}
```

When I compile `master.tex` (either with texmaker or from console with pdflatex) I get an error. If I open `test.tex` with texmaker, instead of 'eñe' I have 'EÃ±e'. But if I open it with gvim, I have 'ñ'. When I fix it from textmaker, everything works just fine.

There is a workaround that I don't want to use:
In the gnuplot script, instead of 'eñe' I can write 'e\\~ne'. That works, but I really don't want to do it that way.

I've tried using `set encoding` to `utf8` and `iso_8859_1` in the gnuplot script with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to `set encoding iso_8859_1` in the gnuplot file, you must also save it as Latin-1; the output "EÃ±e" is a clear indication of a two byte UTF-8 character interpreted as Latin-1. Why don't you switch to UTF-8 in all cases?

Comment: Setting the encoding with `set enconding iso_8859_1` and saving the script as Latin-1 worked. Why I don't switch to UTF-8 in all cases? I don't know, maybe historical reasons, maybe in the future I'll ask myself the same question and change. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
```

in the Gnuplot file, you must ensure it is Latin-1 encoded to begin with. I made my test with Emacs, adding the line

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

at the start, which is the incantation for setting the desired file encoding. Other editors have their own methods.

---

I recommend you to switch to UTF-8 for the LaTeX files. The `[utf8]` option to `inputenc` has proved very robust and it's possible to extend the known characters (`inputenc` doesn't load a definition for each Unicode character, as it would mean defining scores of useless fonts) with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` commands or with the `newunicodechar` package, in case of need.

Comment: I think that I use latin1 because of Windows defaults (with Argentina settings). I'll have in mind what you said and I'll give it a try to utf8. For future reference, I changed the encoding in vim with `set encoding latin1` or `set encoding fileencoding latin1`